# App.Config - client app or class library

Tags: vb.net

I have experience using the Web.Config file in ASP.NET.  I am trying to add an app.config file to a VB.NET project.

I am able to retrieve a connection string in one of the classes (in the class library) if I add the app.config to the client application, but I am unable to do so if I add the app.config to the Class Library project (I get a "object is not an instance" error).  What is the difference between adding the app.config to the client app and adding it to the class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app.config always belongs to the executable assembly. If a library tries to read the app.config, it will be actually reading the app.config that belongs to whichever executable is using that library. That is why you can put settings in your executable's app.config which apply to various .NET framework libraries.

Comment: Thanks.  How does this work with ASP.NET? i.e. if you wanted to add a DLL to your ASP.NET project.  The DLL and the ASP.NET files currently use one config file (the web.config).  I want to put the classes into a DLL.

Comment: @w0051977 I'm not very familiar with ASP, but I believe it all works the same.  I think if the project loading the DLL is an ASP.NET project, then when the DLL loads the settings, it actually reads from the that ASP.NET project's web.config file.

Comment: Does the DLL look at the import statements contained in the web.config? For example, I have imported System.Web in the web.config, but System.Web.HttpException causes an error in the DLL i.e. it is underlined in blue.

Comment: No, the import statements in the web.config will only apply to the ASP.NET project.  To import project-wide namespaces in a library project, you need to go to the References tab of the project properties and select the desired namespaces in the "Imported Namespaces" list at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Can I ask one more question before answering.  What is the point of an app.config in a class library, if the class library always uses the config file in the exe?

Comment: There is no point.  It will never be used--not by the standard classes that operate on the app.config, anyway.

Comment: Nothing will use it, unless you write code to load it and parse it yourself.